# Is it possible to transfer magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism

I wonder if you can transfer magnetic force, i.e. magnetize a metal and demagnetize the former magnet. Is this possible? If so, how you do it?

Comment: Do you mean a process that magnetizes a metal *at the expense* of the magnetic field of another magnet? I believe you can end up with both of them magnetized if you want: use the field of the magnet you have to align the spins of the electrons on your other piece of metal while cooling it down. At the end of the process, you should have two magnets.

Comment: @Níckolas Alves No, i need one magnetized and one demagnetized. So it's like moving its force from A to B partially or completely, and the force stays in B and can be moved to A again if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with coupled inductors. The changing magnetic field of one inductor creates an EMF and current in the other inductor, causing that one to emit a magnetic field.